# Relation between Corr(X,Y) and Corr(X^2,Y^2)

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to find if there's any equation that relates  Correlation Coefficient between X and Y to the Correlation Coefficient between X^2 and Y^2. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are the variables positive?